# How to redirect website to mobile but not image folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mobile, url-rewriting

I've added this code in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/ [L,R=302]
```

and I have all of the images in the http://www.exemple.com/imgs folder.

When I try to load those images from my mobile, the path seems wrong because of that redirection and even if I call the image with the full path, it's not working.

Is there any workaround so the redirection works and loads images from the path where there are and not trying to load them with forcing the redirection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in the same order:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/imgs/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/ [L,R=302]
```

also, did you miss, `$1` after `/mobile/` in `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/ [L,R=302]`?

Comment: The `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REQUEST} ^/imgs/ [NC]` is making the mobile redirect not working anymore :S

Comment: @Warface My bad. Had missed `!`. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
RewriteCond    $1    !^(imgs)
```

should do the trick

Comment: @Warface `$1` is also dependant on `rewriterule`. So, if any rewrite rule is added in the future before `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` depending on grouping, this will stop working.